# Integral with two variables.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

In my calculus class, this theorem was presented :

Let $f :J\times I \rightarrow R$  where $I,J$ are two open set and $f$ a $C^1$ function. Let $a,b : I \rightarrow J $ two $C^1$ functions. 
Then :
$$g(y)=\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)}f(x,y)dx$$
Is $C^1(I)$ and 
$$g'(y):=f(b(y),y)b'(y)-f(a(y),y)a'(y)+\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}dx$$
But, in my series, I'm given this function : 
$$f(x,y)=\int_{-x^2}^{y^2}\cosh{(yt^2+x})dt$$
I have two compute the gradient of this function but i have no idea how to compute $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$. Can someone explain me how to compute this ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compute $\frac\partial{\partial y}f(x,y)$, you apply that theorem with $a(y)=-x^2$ (it will be a constant function then) and $b(y)=y^2$. And, in order to compute $\frac\partial{\partial x}f(x,y)$, you apply that theorem with $a^\star(x)=-x^2$  and $b^\star(x)=y^2$ (now, this one will be constant).

Comment: Okay, so if $g(x,y,z)=\cosh(yz^2+x)$, does it mean that : $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=g(x,y^2,z)(y^2)'-g(-x^2,y,z)\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(-x^2)+\int_{-x^2}^{y^2}\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x,y,t)dt $ ?

Comment: No. Why change $t$ into $z$? In this context, $t$ is a constant. You could have, say, $\sqrt2$ instead of $t^2$.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure to understand...

Comment: Then please explain why you think that something is gained if $t$ becomes $z$.

Comment: I did this because I wanted to apply the previous theorem... Because in the theorem, we integrate with a variable $x$ which is an argument of the function $f$. It was more clear for me if the argument of $g$ were $x,y,z$ instead of $x,y,t$.

Comment: So do we have then : $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\cosh(y(y^2)^2+x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}y^2+\cosh(y(-x^2)^2+x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(-x)^2+\int_{-x^2}^{y^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\cosh(yt^2+x)dx$

Comment: I had not noticed that the integration was with respect to $t$. Therefore, $t$ is *not* a constant. Sorry about that. But what I wrote in my answer still stands. And$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=2x\cosh(yx^2+x)+\int_{-x^2}^{y^2}\sinh(yt^2+x)\,\mathrm dt.$$

Comment: Okay, I think it is clear for me know ! Thank you José !

Comment: I think that you made a mistake ? The result is : $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=2x\cosh(yx^4+x)+\int_{-x^2}^{y^2}\sinh(yt^2+x)dt$